# How to get an older version of OpenStreetMap data?

Tags: openstreetmap

For some reason in the map of the Dominican Republic's Capital there are a bunch of streets which doesn't have any names. I had an OSM file which I downloaded ealier this year which did have those streets name.

I really don't know WHY the names has just dissapeared, but I would like to know if there is a way that I can get them back.

Maybe I can download an older version and then re-upload it so the current version get the streets' names back.

So can you tell me how to get an older version of the OpenStreetMap or can you give me any other alternatives to get the streets' names back?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The License changed - http://blog.osmfoundation.org/2012/09/12/openstreetmap-data-license-is-odbl/ users who contributed but did not accept the license would have features/attributes removed.

Comment: But is there a way that I could get an older/complete version?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, (as far as I know) there's no feature in the OSM API to find out when a particular feature(s) (for example, if you knew the name of the street or even the OSM way ID) was deleted.

However, previous versions of OSM data exist, however the old data that OSM hosts only are [planet.osm extracts](http://planet.openstreetmap.org/cc-by-sa/) (which can contain all of the data from OSM, 20+ gigabytes!). You could then extract out the Dominican Republic from the planet.osm . The redaction of data (for the change of OSM License) was in July 2012, so it would be a good idea to get an extract from June to see if your streets were still there.

NOTE: You would be violating OSM's ODBL license if you were to now upload the data from an old planet.osm extract that was licensed under CC-BY-SA.

Comment: There are also smaller datasets from before-redaction-bot available: http://download.geofabrik.de/osm-before-redaction/central-america/

Answer (score 2):

You can always try one of the OSM mirrors that hasn't been updated in a while. e.g. http://download.cloudmade.com/americas/caribbean/dominican_republic#downloads_breadcrumbs (last updated December 2011)

If the license has changed I'm not sure how this affects the legality of using the data, but perhaps if it was legal at the time it was exported it still is now? If anyone has more than just uninformed guesses I'd be interested to hear it.

Comment: I would say that's a very ad-hock solution: the mirrors are updated over time so you will only get the previous 6 months or so... What's needed IMO is a longer-term solution, that allows you to select the date at which the OSM map existed. This would allow you to see back in time. Would be a valuable resource for research - someone must have this data, but where is it accessible? This is the key question for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to receive historical OpenStreetMap data:

1. Historical OSM data is available in the **OpenStreetMap Full History Dump** file. You can dowload it as *.pbf or *.xml data. Extracts of selected countries can be downloaded from http://osm.personalwerk.de/full-history-extracts/ or from http://odbl.poole.ch/extracts/. I recommend you the [OSM-history-splitter](https://github.com/MaZderMind/osm-history-splitter) to generate extracts out of *.osh files and the [OSM-history-renderer](https://github.com/MaZderMind/osm-history-renderer) import the data into a PostGIS database. 
   After importing the data you will have two columns showing the "validity" of every OSM feature. The first column "valid_from" shows the date when the feature was created initially or modified in the future and the second column "valid_to" shows the date until when it was valid. You will also see the tag-changes for every single version and it's possible to query the columns to identify changes.
2. If you're only interested in a few OSM-features you can simply search for a road (or every other OSM-feature) with the **OSM-API** using its osm-id. For example http://www.openstreetmap.org/way/28150907/history shows the entired history for the road with the osm-id "28150907" (Avenida de Los Próceres).